Jenkins, install custom plugin at each restart
I have a Jenkins installation deployed via Kubernetes, i use a controller as explained in at the page in the link.
In the controller, i define (under the installPlugins entry) a set of plugins that will be reinstalled once the Jenkins instance restarts, for example:
installPlugins:
      - 'java'
      - 'kotlin'
      - 'groovy'

But i also have a 'custom' plugin, this is a file i build on Jenkins itself in a dedicate pipeline and i archive as build artifact.
It sometimes happens that Jenkins crashes and restarts, the plugins defined in the installPlugins keyword  in the controller definition are successfully installed, but how can i also tell the controller that i want to install the custom plugin?
I could put it in some repository accessible via HTTP(S) for example and specify the URL under the 'installPlugins' keyword, but it wont work
I cant find any documentation on this topic, any idea? 
Thanks!

do you have a custom update center hosting your plugin?
